# How can I write this array to one cell and have it like a text using GAS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This seems simple, but I'm sure.

The array is writte like this:
`["amarelo primavera","amarelo suave","amarelo suave + azul céu","azul caribe"]`

But it should be written like this:
`amarelo primavera, amarelo suave, amarelo suave + azul céu, azul caribe`

I'm using `setValue()` to range `A1` and I've tried `replace()`, `JSON.stringify()`, but none of them get me where I need.

Here's the output I get, when using the suggestion you made:
[image]

Here's the code snippet:

```
function pasteColors(selectedColors) {
  const cadProdutoSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Cadastro de Produto');
  Logger.log('SelectedeColor Array: ' + selectedColors);
  cadProdutoSheet.getRange("D39").setValue(JSON.stringify(selectedColors));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  let a  = JSON.parse(cadProdutoSheet.getRange("D39").getValue());
  Logger.log('A: ' + a);
  cadProdutoSheet.getRange(39,4).setValue(a.join(","));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you are passing selectedColors as an Array.  This error would occur if it was a string.  Check typeof a before you execute a.join().

Comment: You're right, @TheWizEd! Although I was returning an array from another function, it arrived as string to my surprise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const array = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(array));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  let a = JSON.parse(sh.getRange(1,1).getValue());
  Logger.log(a.join(','));
  sh.getRange(2,1).setValue(a.join(","));
}

Execution log
3:34:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:34:11 PM  Info    a,b,c,d,e
3:34:11 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

CELL:

[image]

Comment: You're probably going to hate me for this (too), but added the code above, resulting in the error: ```TypeError: a.join is not a function```

Comment: I tested it and it works for me